# Join with a second table containing multiple records, take the latest

Tags: sql, group-by, left-join, greatest-n-per-group, amazon-redshift

I have two tables:

```
person_id | name
1            name1
2            name2
3            name3
```

and a second table:

```
person_id | date     | balance
1           2016-03     1200                    ---- \
1           2016-04     700                     ----  > same person
1           2016-05     400                     ---- /
3           2016-05     4000
```

Considering that person_id 1 has three record on the second table how can I join the first just by taking the latest record? (that is: balance 400, corresponding to date: 2016-05).

E.g.: query output:

```
person_id | name    | balance
1           name1     400
2           name2     ---
3           name3     4000
```

if it's possibile prefer the simplicity over the complexity of the solution

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: AWS Redshift  a flavour of postregres with less functions (if possibile the query should be mysql compatible)

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A query working for all DB engines is

```
select t1.name, t2.person_id, t2.balance
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.person_id = t2.person_id
join
(
    select person_id, max(date) as mdate
    from table2
    group by person_id
) t3 on t2.person_id = t3.person_id and t2.date = t3.mdate
```

Comment: does this consider the case when a record is not found in the 2nd table (as the example)? Or do i have to replace your join with a left join?

Comment: If you want always want a `person_id`  you have to use a left join

Comment: No, because when you group then you can only select columns you group by or aggregate (with  for instance max(), min(), ...)

Comment: @jurgen d: the answer provided by rigerta makes only 1 join, do you this he is correct?

Comment: No, because with the TOP 1/LIMIT 1 the subquery returns only one single record

Comment: do you think using this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Examples_of_firstlast_WF.html could simplify the query?

Comment: If you want to use a window function your are good with Gordons answer.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this in any database that supports the ANSI standard window functions (which is most of them) is:

```
select t1.*, t2.balance
from table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person_id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.person_id = t2.person_id and seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: interesting the use with only one join, anyway do you think thay by using first_value of windows like this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Examples_of_firstlast_WF.html it would be a bit simplified?

Comment: @gio . . . Alas, `first_value()` is a window function, not an aggregation function, so it doesn't reduce the number of rows.  You still need a subquery and filtering, so the answer is equivalent.

Comment: ok thank you +1! Anyway I tagged this question as greatest-n-per-group as I think is basically the same thing. Sadly so many questions on this matter, when a simple FIRST() or LAST() function implemented in database could solve all problem